# How to execute synchronous queries on local database using javascript in windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: cordova, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1, web-sql, local-database

I am using WebSQL plugin https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql for a windows phone 8.1 phonegap app. Below is the code.

```
var db = openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, function () {
    //showMessage('db successfully opened or created',"Success");
});
function getPid() {    
    if(pid==0){
        return getSetting("pid");
    } else {
        return 0;
    }    
}
function getSetting(key)
{
    if(key.length == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    db.transaction(function (tx1) {
        tx1.executeSql("SELECT KEY_VAL FROM TABLE_SETTINGS WHERE KEY_NAME='"+key+"' LIMIT 1",[],function(t,data){
            if (data.rows.length > 0) {
                return data.rows[0].KEY_VAL;             
            }            
        }, onError);
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Since tx1.executeSql() is a asynchronous function, I get two pid values as 0 and then the correct value.
How can I get the correct value from the 1st time only as I need to use this value in another query?